# Calculating the previous quarter from the current Month in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, calendar

I'm sure there is a more consise way of achieving this result? However I created the following method to work out the previous quarter from the current month or DateTime passed in.

```
void Main()
{
    var q = Helpers.PreviousQuarter();
    q.Dump();
}

public class Helpers
{
    public static int PreviousQuarter(DateTime? date = null)
    {
        var quarters = new Dictionary<int, int[]>();
        quarters.Add(1, new[] { 1, 2, 3 });
        quarters.Add(2, new[] { 4, 5, 6 });
        quarters.Add(3, new[] { 7, 8, 9 });
        quarters.Add(4, new[] { 10, 11, 12 });

        foreach (var q in quarters)
        {
            if (q.Value.Any(m=> m == (date.HasValue ? date.Value.Month : DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3).Month)))
            return q.Key;
        }

        throw new ArgumentException("Could not calulate quarter.");
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "previous" quarter, your code is suppose to return the current quarter for a DateTime

Comment: Should've made that clearer, the default if no datetime is specified will give the previous quarter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private int PreviousQuarter(DateTime date)
{
        return (int)Math.Ceiling((double)date.AddMonths(-3).Month / (double)3);
}
```

Comment: This will work as well: (date.AddMonths(-3).Month + 2) / 3;

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
public static int PreviousQuarter(DateTime? date = null)
{
 int month;
   if (date.HasValue){
     month =  date.Value.Month;
   } else { 
     month = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3).Month)
   }
 float quarter =   month / 4;
 return (int)Math.Ceiling(quarter +0.1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is returning current quarter for a date you can modify your method like:

```
public static int CurrentQuarter(DateTime? date = null)
{
    return (((date ?? DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3)).Month - 1) / 3) + 1;
}
```

If you want to calculate **previous** quarter then you can use a single array instead of a dictionary like:

```
public static int PreviousQuarter(DateTime? date = null)
{
    int[] previousQuarter = new[] {4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3};
    return previousQuarter[(date ?? DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3)).Month];
}
```